# Turn off auto-refresh in suggested/linked questions while mouse is over that area

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, similar-questions

Diligently while writing a question I read the suggestions for already-asked questions.

It frustrates me quite a lot that I see a question listed that looks relevant, try to click it and the darn thing disappears and is replaced by something else that then receives the click.

It's as annoying as poorly designed carousels on homepages that scroll out of the way when you were reading.

For desktop users it would be great if this did not refresh while the mouse was over the suggestions, which could be taken as a proxy for "human is reading this and may want to interact".

Comment: There is no such auto refresh. The list is updated when you change the title, body, or tags.

Comment: That might be the technical truth. The user reality (perhaps caused by it taking SE a long time to do the search) is that this is a constant frustration. i.e. I have had time to make some text changes, then move the mouse and start reading the suggestions. I have usually read a few suggestions before it refreshes. (I am not on a slow internet connection)

Comment: So sounds like a really slow connection. All in all, not sure how feasible is your request, technically, but let the team decide. :)

Comment: Having done some tests, the POST request typically takes <200ms. I think it's some other quirk